# Jquery: как проверить, был ли клик (и если был, запретить выполнение другой функции)

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Есть сайте-одностраничнике есть две функции. Одна при клике на пункт меню подсвечивает этот пункт и скроллит страницу к нужному блоку:

```
$('nav li a').click(function(){
    // здесь реализация
});
```

А другая подсвечивает тот или иной пункт меню просто при скролле страницы при прохождении того или иного блока:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    // здесь реализация
});
```

Задача - сделать так, чтобы при клике (то есть срабатывании первой функции) вторая бы не срабатывала.

Подскажите, как корректно прописать if(click)?

Comment: так вторая вроде и не должна выполняться

Comment: Можно через глобальную переменную попробовать. Сохранять в ней значение при клике. А во второй функции проверять, есть ли в переменной нужное значение. Если есть, подсвечивать, нет - нет.

Comment: @Grundy, выполняется, потому что первая при клике скроллит страницу (вторая отзывается автоматически на этот скроллинг)

Comment: @mccrush буду благодарен, если приведёте конкретный рабочий пример. Потому что я пробовал делать флаг, который при клике меняет значение. Но вторая функция сразу обращается к флагу напрямую и не учитывает, было ли его значение изменено при клике или нет.

Comment: покажи код, как именно скроллится страница

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное, самый простой способ:

```js
var onScroll = true;
console.log(onScroll);
$('button.scroll').click(function() {
  onScroll = false;
  console.log(onScroll);
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 5000
  }, 2000, function() {
    onScroll = true;
    console.log(onScroll);
  });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (onScroll) {
    console.log('scroll отлавливается');
  } else {
    console.log('scroll не отлавливается');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="scroll">прокрутить</button>
```

Comment: Ну, собственно это и имел ввиду. Второй вопрос: как это реализовать без глобальной переменной?

Comment: Не, так не работает. Условие всегда будет true.

Comment: @humster_spb я так понимаю, у вас странциа прокручивается через `.animate()`?

Comment: @Cheg, первая функция, которая по клику, - да, через .animate()

Comment: @humster_spb обновил ответ

Comment: @Cheg, виноват, закешировался скрипт и потому не срабатывал. Сейчас всё ок, спасибо!

Comment: @humster_spb для наглядности добавил "сообщения")

Answer (score 3):

Если правильно понял:

```
var ifClick = false;
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
  // здесь реализация
  ifClick = true;
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (ifClick) {
    console.log('Клик был');
    // здесь реализация
  } else {
    console.log('Клика не было');
    // здесь реализация
  }

});
```

Пример на [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mccrush/10nhx0gd/)

Comment: ну, только наоборот - изначально true (чтобы при обычно скролле работало), а при клике - false, да.